emacs markdown mode and markdown-preview disagree out code-block syntax
In emacs markdown-mode, I can denote a code block using 3 back-ticks before and after the block.
markdown mode seems to recognize this just fine.  However, when I use the markdown-preview command to render for the web browser, the supposed code-block is rendered all one one line.
I think the problem is the unix command markdown expects 4 char or TAB indentation of a code block.
How should I fix this?   Which unix command should I use to agree with the markdown-mode syntax?  The elisp variable markdown-command is not documented well enough to know which values to use to be compatible with the emacs mode (rendering within an emacs buffer).
I installed the unix markdown using brew install markdown which seems to have installed

This is Markdown, version 1.0.1.
Copyright 2004 John Gruber
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/



I use "pandoc -f markdown -t html5" as markdown-command and either 4 spaces or backticks are recognized as code in markdown-preview
